# count number of instances for each object in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 tables

```
code {
id, 
name,
fiveDigit,
startDate,
endDate,
promo_code_id
}

promo_code {
id,
description,
title,
extraDigit,
createdDate
}

company {
id,
name
}

promo_code_company {
id,
promo_code_id,
company_id
}
```

I need query that will return me list of all codes -> promo codes and i need 2 extra attributes that will show me number of companies each promo code have and one attribute that will show me name of just one company *i just need to show one company even if promo code have more than one company.

I know how to join this tables to get all informations but i have no idea how i can get numberOfCompanies for each promo code. 
I expect response something like this:

```
name             fiveDigit         title          numberOfComapnies  companyName
super code       12345           some title            11             sample
```

I already tried something like this

```
SELECT pc.id, c.id
count(pc.id) numberOfComapnies,
FROM code c
LEFT OUTER JOIN promo_code pc ON pc.Id=c.promo_code_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN promo_code_company pcc ON pcc.promo_code_id = pc.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN company co on co.id = pcc.company_id
GROUP BY pc.Id, c.id
```

When i do that i get list of promo codes but i get numberOfCompanies 1 on every promo code. Basically i need to do counting in many to many table promo_code_company but i'm not sure how to do that. And if i remove from GROUP BY one field i get error like this

**must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function**

EDIT: so i made that query work, and now im wondering how i can write name of 1 company, when i for example select c.id, then my counting dont work so i need a way to write just one company name, for example first one, any suggestions ?

Comment: `count(c.id)` instead of `count(pc.id)`

Comment: I'm still getting 2 same codes but with different comapnies and with numbeerOfCompanies 1 for each...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT pc.id, pc.name, pc.description, c.name
MAX(co.name) companyName,
count(pc.id) numberOfComapnies,
FROM code c
LEFT OUTER JOIN promo_code pc ON pc.Id=c.promo_code_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN promo_code_company pcc ON pcc.promo_code_id = pc.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN company co on co.id = pcc.company_id
GROUP BY pc.id, c.id
```

This is solution in case anyone ever need it.